# JSON.parse: unexpected character?

Tags: jquery, json, django

I am using the jQuery `getJSON` method, but the returned data from a Python Django view causes the error `JSON.parse: unexpected character`

Below is the JSON structure:

```
OK[
   {
      "status":"FINISHED",
      "transcoded_file_link":"/download_xml_file/5",
      "name":"uploads/vid2.avi",
      "original_file_link":"/download_file/uploads/vid2.avi"
   },
   {
      "status":"FINISHED",
      "transcoded_file_link":"/download_xml_file/6",
      "name":"uploads/vid2_1.avi",
      "original_file_link":"/download_file/uploads/vid2_1.avi"
   },
   {
      "status":"FINISHED",
      "transcoded_file_link":"/download_xml_file/7",
      "name":"uploads/vid2_2.avi",
      "original_file_link":"/download_file/uploads/vid2_2.avi"
   }
]
```

Comment: That 'OK' at the beginning of your string is causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments provided the **problem is with that 'OK'** at the beginning.

Use like below part only with out 'OK'

```
[{"status": "FINISHED", "transcoded_file_link": "/download_xml_file/5", "name": "uploads/vid2.avi", "original_file_link": "/download_file/uploads/vid2.avi"}, {"status": "FINISHED", "transcoded_file_link": "/download_xml_file/6", "name": "uploads/vid2_1.avi", "original_file_link": "/download_file/uploads/vid2_1.avi"}, {"status": "FINISHED", "transcoded_file_link": "/download_xml_file/7", "name": "uploads/vid2_2.avi", "original_file_link": "/download_file/uploads/vid2_2.avi"}]
```